# Why does this variable change when I don't change it within this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

This function takes in two arrays, arrOne, which is an array of arrays of numbers, and arrTwo, which is an array of numbers. I am trying to make it produce every combination and then eventually every unique combination, however I am facing an issue.

```js
function multOrdProduct(arrOne,arrTwo){
  let backSet = [];
  let count = 0;
  let tempArr = new Array(arrOne.length);
  let permArrOne = [];
  let permArrTwo = [];
  let pushed;
  let setPart = [];
  
  for(i=0; i < arrOne.length; i++){
    permArrOne.push(arrOne[i]);
  }
// ^sets permArrOne to equal the same array as ArrOne
  
  for(i = 0; i < arrOne.length;i++){
    for(j = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++){

      setPart = permArrOne[i];
      
      console.log(permArrOne[i]);
      
      setPart.push(arrTwo[j]);
      backSet.push(setPart);
    }
  }
  return backSet;
}
```

I would have thought that `permArrOne[i]` would not change as I do not set any value to it, however why does it change with each loop?

Comment: `push` adds to the array, it doesn't make them the same

Comment: @evolutionxbox When I log permArrOne, before the second for loop, it is the same as ArrOne though, the problem I am having is why does permArrOne change in the second for loop as it is not being changed by anything I can see

Comment: `setPart` is a reference to `permArrOne[i]` not a copy of it, so changes to `setPart` will make changes to `permArrOne[i]`

Answer (score 0):

As youre just referencing permArrOne in setPart and not cloning it, youre changing permArrOne as youre changing setPart.

.slice() is one way to reference a new array:

```js
function multOrdProduct(arrOne,arrTwo){
  let backSet = [];
  let count = 0;
  let tempArr = new Array(arrOne.length);
  let permArrOne = [];
  let permArrTwo = [];
  let pushed;
  let setPart = [];
  
  for(i=0; i < arrOne.length; i++){
    permArrOne.push(arrOne[i]);
  }
// ^sets permArrOne to equal the same array as ArrOne
  
  for(i = 0; i < arrOne.length;i++){
    for(j = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++){

      setPart = permArrOne[i].slice();
      
      console.log(permArrOne[i]);
      
      setPart.push(arrTwo[j]);
      backSet.push(setPart);
    }
  }
  return backSet;
}

let arr1 = [[0, 1], [1, 2]]

let arr2 = [0, 1, 2]

multOrdProduct(arr1, arr2)
```